# Iframe url cant be opened in html5?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQBzT3XBwzU" width="600" height="600">
        <p>Youtube</p>
        </iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code show me empty frame and i dont know why. I tried some other urls and some of them works and some dont

Comment: Look at the error in the dev tools console.

Comment: If i put https://net.hr/ it works but some sites wont work hmm

Comment: Look at the error in the dev tools console.

Comment: It's something with popular sites like youtube, facebook etc. regional web sites work.

Comment: Yes, as the error in the dev tools console is trying to tell you.

Comment: I dont know where to find it in visual code studio

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a `does not permit cross-origin framing issue.` Check your console.